# Meaning of array[..., np.newaxis) with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

consider the following code :

```
test_1 = np.zeros((2, 2))
test_2 = np.zeros((2, 2, 1))
print(test_1[..., np.newaxis])
print(test_1[np.newaxis])
```

Result :

```
[[[0.]
  [0.]]

 [[0.]
  [0.]]]
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]]
```

I really don't understand the meaning of this '...' and why the two lines don't produce a similar array. Do you have an idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: `...` means "all existing dimensions", `np.newaxis`/`None` adds a new one

Comment: One adds the new dimension at the end, making a (2,2,1).  The other adds it at the beginning, making a (1,2,2).  In a case like this, displaying the `shape` instead of the array may be more instructive - though deducing the shape from the display is a good exercise.